# Cron running tasks at second 26?

Tags: cron, date, curl

I've many vps with the same cron task sending data with curl every minute, e.g. *date* command output.

So I'm receiving datetime from every vps and I just realized that one of them is running the cron task at HH:MM:26, while anyothers do it at HH:MM:01 or :02.

Why is this vps getting this delay? load average and CPU usage are normals and stables.

**Edit:** Apparently, it isn't about cron, is the vps what is delaying some services or something.

Comment: Are you using the same NTP server for all machines?

Comment: Yes, and I get the same time in different servers, is that crontask what runs later :(

Comment: try running hwclock command. If the time is different from the date command. You must call hwclock --systohc which will sync the two times and run the cronjobs at the expected time.

Comment: nop, time is the same from both commands :/

Comment: ok then verifie if the command  crontab -l shows  correct times

Comment: which times? I setted it to run every minute, so it's : * * * * * [command], however, cron granularity is minutes. Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: ok I forget the syntax of cron. in any case the crond daemon runs every 30 seconds to verifie if anything must be run. I think that there is some running process causing this delay. try restarting cron

Comment: wow, I just realized about something worse, it must not be a cron problem... If I attempt to connect via SSH it won't till second reachs ~24, it's like if the cpu is blocked and it gets free at this time... however, there are many websites running without problem... that's weird

Comment: And once I connect, I can type any command without any trouble, afaik, is just to run a crontask and to accept an ssh connection what are delayed :S any clue?

Comment: SSH logins and cron having an initial delay sounds like something in your shells startup files is taking a lot of time. I'm not sure about other shells but at least bash and zsh can be called with `-x` to show what they're doing. Maybe try that and check if there is any command taking a long time there.